# Dekker's root-finding method and fixed interval border (should shrink to root)

Tags: nonlinear-equations, roots

Dekker's method and in its evolution Brent's method have as design goal to combine the certainty of a root, certified by function values of opposite sign in an increasingly smaller interval, of bracketing methods like bisection and regula falsi with the fast convergence of the secant (and higher degree of (reverse) interpolation) methods. Especially in the regula falsi method without modification one observes with regularity that one border of the bracketing interval becomes fixed, which causes the convergence to be linear, sometimes even slower than the bisection method.

---

Why experiment with the Dekker's method, not Brent's method? I have implemented Brent's method based on English Wiki but I can't understand two conditionals for $\delta$: condition 4 and condition 5.

If $\delta$ is rather big (for example $10^{-4}$) this conditionals are bad, if $\delta$ is small ($10^{-14}$) it is no difference in my sample functions.

---

I try to implement Dekker's method to explore functions with bad behaviour. I have written code based on Wikipedia and [1]. But in both cases is the same.

I do with $$f(x) = (x + 3)(x − 1)^2~~\text{ and range }~~[−4, 4/3].$$
$4/3$ is near the root $1$, $-4$ is further away from the root $-3$. The sequence of iteration points approaches $1$ but the left border point of the range is always $-4$.

```
#Based on [1]
a1=-4.00000000 b1=1.33333333 c1=-4.00000000
a2= 1.33333333 b2=1.23255814 c2=-4.00000000
a3= 1.23255814 b3=1.14122330 c3=-4.00000000
a4= 1.14122330 b4=1.08966720 c4=-4.00000000
a5= 1.08966720 b5=1.05556489 c5=-4.00000000
```

The contrapoint $c_i$ is always $-4$.

> Do I have an error in implementation or has this method this bad behaviour in this function? How to modify point $c_i$ ?

**References**

1. Bus, J. C. P., and T. J. Dekker. ["Two efficient algorithms with guaranteed convergence for finding a zero of a function."](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/20561/20561A.pdf) ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software (TOMS) 1.4 (1975): 330-345.

Comment: Implementation is on Disk Google: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7E799YMGCWTWWJFdWZmXzVrUjQ. Function Dekker::find is based on WIkpedia, Dekker::verboseA is literal, without loops implementation of 20561A.pdf

Comment: [Brent's Method by Oscar Veliz](https://youtu.be/-bLSRiokgFk) is an excellent explanation of Brent's method.

Answer (score 2):

A full log of the Dekker method run as in [1] confirms your observation and shows that the example is indeed a bad situation for the Dekker method, a combination of a multiple root inside the start interval and just the right interval. Letting it run for much more steps, the output reads

```
       ,        ,         -> initial   : x[ 0] =  -4.000000000000000,  f(x[ 0]) = -25.000000000000000
a=x[ 0],        ,         -> initial   : x[ 1] =   1.333333333333333,  f(x[ 1]) =   0.481481481481481
a=x[ 0], b=x[ 1], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[ 2] =   1.232558139534884,  f(x[ 2]) =   0.228910661954293
a=x[ 1], b=x[ 2], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[ 3] =   1.141223295849618,  f(x[ 3]) =   0.082592637299225
a=x[ 2], b=x[ 3], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[ 4] =   1.089667203324025,  f(x[ 4]) =   0.032881772315203
a=x[ 3], b=x[ 4], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[ 5] =   1.055564885924540,  f(x[ 5]) =   0.012521380362105
a=x[ 4], b=x[ 5], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[ 6] =   1.034592397360872,  f(x[ 6]) =   0.004827930257963
a=x[ 5], b=x[ 6], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[ 7] =   1.021431369375937,  f(x[ 7]) =   0.001847057878276
a=x[ 6], b=x[ 7], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[ 8] =   1.013276313630701,  f(x[ 8]) =   0.000707382104210
a=x[ 7], b=x[ 8], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[ 9] =   1.008214575350145,  f(x[ 9]) =   0.000270471306102
a=x[ 8], b=x[ 9], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[10] =   1.005081086844448,  f(x[10]) =   0.000103400954756
a=x[ 9], b=x[10], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[11] =   1.003141749908864,  f(x[11]) =   0.000039513380892
a=x[10], b=x[11], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[12] =   1.001942302905629,  f(x[12]) =   0.000015097489725
a=x[11], b=x[12], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[13] =   1.001200628613113,  f(x[13]) =   0.000005767766984
a=x[12], b=x[13], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[14] =   1.000742115041459,  f(x[14]) =   0.000002203347648
a=x[13], b=x[14], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[15] =   1.000458684641088,  f(x[15]) =   0.000000841662903
a=x[14], b=x[15], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[16] =   1.000283495152734,  f(x[16]) =   0.000000321500791
a=x[15], b=x[16], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[17] =   1.000175214373124,  f(x[17]) =   0.000000122805685
a=x[16], b=x[17], c=x[ 0] -> minimal   : x[18] =   1.000075214373124,  f(x[18]) =   0.000000022629233
a=x[17], b=x[18], c=x[ 0] -> minimal   : x[19] =   0.999975214373124,  f(x[19]) =   0.000000002457294
a=x[18], b=x[19], c=x[ 0] -> minimal   : x[20] =   0.999875214373124,  f(x[20]) =   0.000000062283868
a=x[19], b=x[20], c=x[ 0] -> midpoint  : x[21] =  -1.500062392813438,  f(x[21]) =   9.375077977391534
a=x[20], b=x[21], c=x[ 0] -> midpoint  : x[22] =  -2.750031196406719,  f(x[22]) =   3.515244786737265
a=x[21], b=x[22], c=x[ 0] -> midpoint  : x[23] =  -3.375015598203360,  f(x[23]) =  -7.178084118186108
a=x[23], b=x[22], c=x[23] -> secant    : x[24] =  -2.955483883754270,  f(x[24]) =   0.696492599989121
a=x[22], b=x[24], c=x[23] -> secant    : x[25] =  -3.006249707390058,  f(x[25]) =  -0.100308033086949
a=x[24], b=x[25], c=x[24] -> secant    : x[26] =  -2.999858874218545,  f(x[26]) =   0.002257853174204
a=x[25], b=x[26], c=x[25] -> secant    : x[27] =  -2.999999560010752,  f(x[27]) =   0.000007039826415
a=x[26], b=x[27], c=x[25] -> minimal   : x[28] =  -3.000099560010753,  f(x[28]) =  -0.001593039470593
exit by interval length
a=x[28], b=x[27], c=x[28] -> best value: x[27] =  -2.999999560010752,  f(x[27]) =   0.000007039826415
```

The interpretation is that the method follows first the secant method in $b_i, a_i=b_{i-1}$ towards the double root $x=1$. Because of the multiplicity the convergence is linear.

As there is no exit condition based on the function value, at the moment that the points $a_i,b_i$ are close enough so that the function values are almost equal the secant root computation fails and Dekker's method nudges the active point over the root with minimal steps. Remember that the method is constructed to find the root by enclosing it in an interval with a sign change in the function values.

Finally, the secant is so horizontal or sloped the wrong way that the secant root falls outside of the bracketing interval $[b_i,c_i]$ ($c_i$ is here still constant $-4$, `c=x[0]` in the table).

After a while the secant root that is still computed close to the double root is safely away from the bracketing interval that the method now leaves the "emergency" mode and switches to the midpoint of the bisection method, until the value at the midpoint changes sign, ending the stalling at $c_i=-4$.

Now the double root is completely "forgotten" and the sign-switching root is found in a few secant steps.

```python
def dekker(f, a, b, tol=1e-7):
    fa, fb = f(a), f(b)
    if fa*fb > 0: 
        error("need sign change in initial interval")
    # [a,b] is bracketing interval, establish triangle formation, [b,c] now also bracketing
    c,fc = a,fa
    while True:
        # make b the best. In superlinear mode nothing should happen here
        if abs(fc) < abs(fb): 
            # A, B, C = B, C, B    # triangle formation
            a,fa, b,fb, c,fc = b,fb, c,fc, b,fb
        # atomic step size
        db = tol
        if abs(c-b)<2*db: print("exit by interval length"); break
        # minimal change in case of stalling
        h = b + (db if c>b else -db);
        # elements of the secant step
        p = fb*(a-b); q = (fb-fa);
        if p<0: p,q = -p,-q
        # default for midpoint step
        v = m = 0.5*(b+c); 
        # secant step if step update is large enough
        if p > abs(db*q):
            s = b+p/q
            # step goes not beyond midpoint, else remain at midpoint
            if p < q*(v-b): v = s;
        else: v = h; 
        # shift the secant sequence
        a,fa, b,fb = b,fb, v,f(v);
        # Now a < b=v <= m < c or in the other direction. Between a and c there is a sign change
        # If the sign also changes between b and c, do nothing, linear formation remains.
        # Else copy a to c, establishing a triangle formation
        if fb*fc > 0:
            c,fc = a,fa
        # Now [b,c] is ensured to be bracketing and (a,b) is ready for the next secant root computation
    return b, c
        
dekker(lambda x: (x+3)*(x-1)**2,-4,4./3, tol=1e-4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, Dekker method has bad behaviour if is more than one root in given interval.

See this method on Cleve’s Corner (http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/10/12/zeroin-part-1-dekkers-algorithm/) where method is good enough for one root in interval.